# Inno Setup launching bat file

Tags: batch-file, installation

I'm using Inno Setup to run pnputil.exe utility.
Here is my code:

```
Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}') + '\driver_install.bat','"'+'pnputil'+'"','',SW_SHOW,ewWaitUntilTerminated,ResultCode);
```

The driver_install.bat contains the following:

```
echo off
echo "PLEASE WAIT WHILE DRIVERS WILL BE INSTALLED"
%~1
echo "IT MAY TAKE 5-10 min"
PAUSE
```

I'm passing the parameter "pnputil" to the bat file. I'm using bat file because i want user to see the output.
The problem is that on windows 8 i get

```
'pnputil' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
```

When i change the pnputil to cmd the output is fine.
The administrator rights are not the cause here because pnputil can be launched from console without administrator rights.

Comment: Try to call pnputil with `%windir%\sysnative\pnputil.exe` instead.

Comment: Thanks MichaelS it worked. I thought pnoutil.exe could be launched in any directory. That's strange for me.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll repost my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call pnputil using `%windir%\sysnative\pnputil.exe` instead.